# What kind if distribution is the problem $p(x-y = k| x>y)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> We choose randomly two numbers $x,y$ out of $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Calculate $P(x-y=k | x>y), 1 \leq k \leq n-1$.

What I said:

> We obviously need a random variable here $X$ that, in the case that $x>y$, represents the equation $x-y$. The outcome of $X$ can be $1,2,..., n-1$. We need $P(X=k)$.

Is my approach correct? What kind of distribtion is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition $P(A|B)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$

Two numbers randomly chosen are independent and have following distribution: $P(x=m)=\frac{1}{m}$

$P(AB)=P(x-y=k,x>y)=1$, since $k>0$

$P(B)=P(x>y)=P(x-y>0)=\sum\limits_{x-y>0} P(x,y)=\sum\limits_{i=2}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{ij}=H_{n-1}(H_n-1)$

Comment: Can you please explain in the last line why $\Sigma_{x-y>0} {P(x,y)} = ...?$

Comment: Nevermind I understood. Thank you!